# installing and setting up firebase cli on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

with node and npm installed, I commenced by running

```
sudo npm install -g firebase-tools
```

on my terminal. On trying out

```
firebase login
firebase: command not found
```

thats the response I get. I tried

```
alias firebase="`npm config get prefix`/bin/firebase"
```

which only works for a single response only. I can't initialize firebase nor serve on the machine.

Its using ubuntu 16.04

Comment: In latest Ubuntu 20.4+ Path sets automatically, In your case you need to set Path manually

Answer (score -1):

try running `sudo firebase login` from what i understand is that if you install at admin level it can only be accessed at admin level too...